# Is there a way to opt-out from WP8 when submiting an Windows Phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone app build using the 7.1 SDK that works great on WP7 but does not work at all on WP8 (I am using multicast using UDP and WP8 can join the group but send/receives no message for some reason, other people having the same problem: [UDP multicast group on Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528262/udp-multicast-group-on-windows-phone-8)).

Is there a way to opt-out from WP8 when I submit my app? I just want the app to be available t WP7 users. I am looking for something like the 256MB opt-out option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to opt-out from having your 7.1 app published and downloadable for Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Why are you talking about 'downloadable for WP 8'?  That doesn't make sense since the app you created is for 7.1 only.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to opt-out for 3rd party apps to opt-out from WP8. A few apps using 1st party APIs on WP7 were opted out from WP8 while they upgraded to WP8, but that's mostly it.

It sounds like you've hit a nasty application comptability bug in your app. Is there a way to get your code to work on WP8? If it's a minor enough change I'd suggest you use a [runtime check](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!co-development-and-porting-guide.html;#toc_Runtimeadaptation) to apply some WP8 specific code. More on sharing code between WP7 and WP8 can be found in this article @ http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!co-development-and-porting-guide.html

```
if (IsRunningOnWP8)
{
// add some WP8 specific UDP Magic
}

public bool IsRunningOnWP8
{
    get
    {
        return Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know about the runtime check nut I cannot use it. Without the funcionality that does not work on wp8 it app is unusable and I would not pass certification if tested on a wp8 device

Answer (score -2):

An app targeted to run on Windows Phone 7.1 will run in a quirks mode on Windows Phone 8.0. This means that API's that introduced breaking changes will preserve their old behavior when running 7.1 apps.

There are some caveats, however, which are documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947(v=vs.105).aspx.

Comment: That does not answer my question. I need an opt-out because regardles what the msdn document says my app does not work on wp8

Comment: @IgorKulman are you sure? You've tried compiling your 7.1 app and then deploying it to the phone 8 emulator?

Comment: @Earlz absolutely sure. The app works on Omnia 7, Lumia 800, Lumia 610 and does not on work on HTC 8X

Comment: @IgorKulman Any chance your capturing the exception that's getting thrown? Does the app launch and than terminate right away? Is there a specific action your doing at launch time? If so, look at the API's you're using and please report back.

Comment: @DaveBost-MSFT no exception thrown, the devices register for multicast and just do not receive ana packet. Exact problem as in the linked post