# Windows Phone 8.1 doesn't send UDP Broadcast

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to send an UDP Broadcast with Windows Phone 8.1. Therefore, I created a UDP Server (a console app) which runs on my laptop in the same Wifi Network as my WP8.1.

This is the test server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new UdpClient(12345);
    client.MulticastLoopback = false;

    var isRunning = true;

    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (isRunning)
        {
            var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            var data = client.Receive(ref endpoint);

            Console.WriteLine("Received message from {0}:{1} with length={2}", endpoint.Address, endpoint.Port, data.Length);
            client.Send(data, data.Length, endpoint);
        }
    });

    thread.Start();

    Console.ReadLine();
    isRunning = false;
}
```

When I create another console app which sends some data as UDP Broadcast, I will get the same data as response from the server. So the server is working fine. With Windows Phone 8.1 I have to use DatagramSocket. This is my code:

```
var socket = new DatagramSocket();
socket.MessageReceived += HandleIncomingMessages;
using (var stream = await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(new HostName("255.255.255.255"), "12345"))
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(data.AsBuffer());
    await stream.FlushAsync();
}
```

I also tried it with an additional `await _socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("255.255.255.255"), "12345");` after creating the `socket` object.

Unfortunately, I'll never get an answer.

Comment: Are you sure that the HostName should be `255.255.255.255`? Or are you just redacting it?

Comment: Many things to check: (1) Have you used a packet-capture tool to see if the broadcast traffic is reaching the server machine? (2) Have you checked the server machine for firewall settings that might be blocking the traffic? (3) Have you tried sending unicast traffic from the phone app (directly to the server's IP) to see if that gets through?

Comment: Also, make sure that you have the Internet capability checked in your manifest.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Sending a UDP Packet to the correct ip address is working fine.

Comment: @NateDiamond The internet capability (Client & Server) is checked. I only know `255.255.255.255` to reach all clients within the same network. Are there other ways to send a UDP broadcast?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UDP multicast group on Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528262/udp-multicast-group-on-windows-phone-8)

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Multicast and Broadcast is not the same

Comment: I know, but the problem may be very much related.

Comment: @MichaelS you can find the IP of the server and enter it manually. If it's a Windows machine (which it sounds like it is), open up command prompt (Windows key, type `cmd`, hit `Enter`). Then, type `ipconfig`. You're looking for the ip of the network adapter that the server is connecting to the network with. Try using that IP address.

Comment: @NateDiamond That's exactly what I did. And when sending the UDP packet directly to the server IP then the server is receiving it.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I can't get multicast working, nor can I get broadcast working (even with the linked multicast question).

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I added my solution as the answer to my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my implementation for a UdpClient which supports broadcast.

```
public class UdpClient : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DatagramSocket _socket;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Tuple<IpAddress, byte[]>> _incomingMessages;
    private readonly IpAddress _ipAddress;
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private bool _isBound;
    private bool _isBinding;

    public UdpClient(IpAddress ipAddress)
    {
        _ipAddress = ipAddress;
        _socket = new DatagramSocket();
        _socket.Control.DontFragment = true;
        _incomingMessages = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<IpAddress, byte[]>>();
        _socket.MessageReceived += HandleIncomingMessages;
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            await Connect();

            using (var stream = await _socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(_ipAddress.Host, _ipAddress.ServiceName))
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(data.AsBuffer(0, data.Length));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetIncomingMessage(out Tuple<IpAddress, byte[]> message)
    {
        return _incomingMessages.TryTake(out message, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _socket.Dispose();
    }

    private async Task Connect()
    {
        if (_isBound || _isBinding)
        {
            return;
        }

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_isBound || _isBinding)
            {
                return;
            }

            _isBinding = true;
        }

        var possibleConnectionProfiles = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles()
            .Where(p => p.IsWlanConnectionProfile && p.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() != NetworkConnectivityLevel.None)
            .ToList();

        var connectionProfile = possibleConnectionProfiles.FirstOrDefault();

        if (connectionProfile != null)
        {
            await _socket.BindServiceNameAsync(_ipAddress.ServiceName, connectionProfile.NetworkAdapter);
        }

        _isBound = true;
        _isBinding = false;
    }

    private void HandleIncomingMessages(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var address = e.RemoteAddress.ToString();
        var port = int.Parse(e.RemotePort);

        using (var reader = e.GetDataReader())
        {
            var data = reader.DetachBuffer().ToArray();
            _incomingMessages.Add(Tuple.Create(new IpAddress(address, port), data));
        }
    }
}

public struct IpAddress
{
    public static readonly IpAddress Broadcast = new IpAddress("255.255.255.255");

    public readonly string Address;
    public readonly int Port;
    public readonly HostName Host;
    public readonly string ServiceName;

    public IpAddress(string address, int port)
    {
        Address = address;
        Port = port;
        Host = new HostName(address);
        ServiceName = port.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:{1}", Address, Port);
    }

    public bool Equals(IpAddress other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Address, other.Address) && Port == other.Port;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        return obj is IpAddress && Equals((IpAddress)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((Address != null ? Address.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ Port;
        }
    }
}
```

I have read that it's not a good habit to broadcast messages to 255.255.255.255. Instead one should send to the local broadcast address like (i.e. 192.168.1.**255**)

For this I wrote this IpAddressProvider:

```
public static class IpProvider
{
    private static readonly Lazy<string> _localAddress;
    private static readonly Lazy<string> _broadcastAddress;

    static IpProvider()
    {
        _localAddress = new Lazy<string>(GetLocalAddress);
        _broadcastAddress = new Lazy<string>(GetBroadcastAddress);
    }

    public static string LocalAddress { get { return _localAddress.Value; } }

    public static string BroadcastAddress { get { return _broadcastAddress.Value; } }

    private static string GetLocalAddress()
    {
        var hostnames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
        foreach (var hn in hostnames)
        {
            //IanaInterfaceType == 71 => Wifi
            //IanaInterfaceType == 6 => Ethernet (Emulator)
            if (hn.IPInformation != null &&
                (hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 71
                 || hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 6))
            {
                return hn.DisplayName;
            }
        }

        return IpAddress.Broadcast.Address;
    }

    private static string GetBroadcastAddress()
    {
        var parts = _localAddress.Value.Split(new[] { '.' }).Take(3);
        return string.Join(".", parts) + ".255";
    }
}
```

And now I use them together to send broadcast messages:

```
var gatewayAddress = new IpAddress(IpProvider.BroadcastAddress);
var udpClient = new UdpClient(gatewayAddress);
await udpClient.SendAsync(data);

Tuple<IpAddress, byte[]> message;
while (udpClient.TryGetIncomingMessage(out message))
{
    if (message.Item1.Address == IpProvider.LocalAddress)
    {
        continue;
    }

    HandleIncomingPacket(message);
}
```